# How to represent association in programs

Tags: programming-languages, c++, object-oriented, class-design, class

Could someone help me in implementing association in cpp. I am trying to implement a dice game where I have two classes a diegame and a dice.

Comment: did you had a chance to follow suggested reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do mean one-to-one associations, they are a very broad kind of connection between types, objects, etc.

For more info have a look at given discussion - [one to one association in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4584518/1437962).